# How to use protobuff in the serviceStack framework

Tags: servicestack, protobuff.net

Do you have a corresponding example? I want to convert the transport format to protolbuff  now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [ServiceStack's ProtoBuf Format docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/protobuf-format) which shows an example of registering the `ProtoBufFormat` plugin as well as info on what you need to decorate your DTOs with so it can be serialized with ProtoBuf.